# Displaying a matplotlib graph in a container

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, kivy-language

I’m working on a newbie app project with Kivy and python to calculate alcohol consumption. The app calculates alcohol input and displays it on a matplotlib graph. I can get the graph to display on a separate screen but I'd like the graph to display above the calculator when the calculate key is pressed.

I’ve tried going through the Kivy documentation but can’t figure it out! I think it may be something to do with box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())) as this displays the graph on a widget but I don't know how to add it to my calculator screen. I've tried using the id: rolling graph in my kivy file (below) but that didn't work. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

main.py...

```
class GraphGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def build(self):
        return GraphGridLayout()

class AlcGridLayout(GridLayout):

    def calculate(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))

                MyApp().run()

            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Something went wrong!"

    def another(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))

            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Something went wrong!"
```

graph.py....

```
class MyApp(App):

    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
    y = [None, 3, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0]

    if y[0] is None:
        y[0] = 0
    else:
        y[0] = 2

    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.ylabel('Alcohol Units')
    plt.xlabel('Day')
    plt.tight_layout(10)


    def build(self):
        box = BoxLayout()

        box.name: box
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))

        return box
```

Alcohol.kv... [there's lots of it so this is the first bit. It would be great to have the graph display at id: rollinggraph/imageview...?]

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 18
    size: 30, 30
    background_color:.50,.50,.50,1

<CustLabel@Label>:
    font_size: 18
    id: label
    color:.25,.80,.92,1
    size: 30, 30
    background_color: .50,.50, .50, 1


<AlcGridLayout>:
    id: rollinggraph
    rows: 16
    padding: 0
    spacing: 0


    # Graph display
    BoxLayout:
        id: imageView
        background_color: .50,.10, .50, 1
```

Comment: I've never seen an `APP` being started inside a `Widget`. Is that call to `MyApp().run()` inside the `AlcGridLayout` what you intended?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, my guess is that all the code that you have in `MyApp` should actually be in the `calculate()` method of `AlcGridLayout`, and `self.ids.imageView.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))` (added to that same method) should display the plot in your `BoxLayout` in `AlcGridLayout`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! It worked and I can move forward with the project now.

Comment: Incidentally, for any other newbies working with Kivy and Matplotlib: If you are displaying your graph in a boxlayout, you can set the graph display height by using size_hint eg. size_hint: 1, 5 . Online docs I found implied 1 is the max but it's not.